# Extract text from background grids/lines [2]

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to remove the grid lines in handwriting picture. I tried to use FFT to extract the grid pattern and remove it (this is from an answer in [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72687514/extract-text-from-background-grids-lines), which is closed somehow. It has more background as well.). This image shows what I am able to get currently ([Illustration result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/832xO.jpg)):

1. The first line is a real image with handwriting character. Since it's taken by phone in various conditions (light, direction, etc.), the grid line might not be perfect horizontal/vertical, and the color of grid line also varies and might be close the the color of characters. I turn it to grayscale, apply fft, and use tries to use thresholding to extract the patterns (in red rectangle, the illustration is using OTSU). Then I mask the image with the thresholding pattern, and use ifft to get the result. It fails on the real image obviously.
2. The second line is a real image of blank grid w/o handwriting character. From this, I think 3 lines (vertical and horizontal) in the center are the patterns I care.
3. The third line is a synthetic image w/ perfect grid lines. It's just for reference. And after applying the same algorithm, the grid lines could be removed successfully.
4. The fourth line is a synthetic image w/ perfect dashed grid lines, which is closer to the grid lines on real handwriting practice paper. It's also for reference. It shows the pattern of dashed lines are actually more complicated than 3 lines in the center. With the same algorithm, the grid lines could be removed almost completely as well.

The code I use is:

```
def FFTCV(img):
    util.Plot(img, 'Input')
    print(img.shape)
    if len(img.shape) == 3 and img.shape[2] == 3:
        img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    util.Plot(img, 'Gray')
    dft = cv.dft(np.float32(img),flags = cv.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
    dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
    util.Plot(cv.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1]), 'fft shift')
    magnitude_spectrum = np.uint8(20*np.log(cv.magnitude(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1])))
    util.Plot(magnitude_spectrum, 'Magnitude')

    _, threshold = cv.threshold(magnitude_spectrum, 0, 1, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    # threshold = cv.adaptiveThreshold(
    #     magnitude_spectrum, 1, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 10)
        # magnitude_spectrum, 1, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 10)
    util.Plot(threshold, 'Threshold Mask')
    fshift = dft_shift * threshold[:, :, None]
    util.Plot(cv.magnitude(fshift[:,:,0],fshift[:,:,1]), 'fft shift Masked')
    magnitude_spectrum = np.uint8(20*np.log(cv.magnitude(fshift[:,:,0],fshift[:,:,1])))
    util.Plot(magnitude_spectrum, 'Magnitude Masked')

    f_ishift = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift)
    img_back = cv.idft(f_ishift)
    img_back = cv.magnitude(img_back[:,:,0],img_back[:,:,1])
    util.Plot(img_back, 'Back')
```

So I'd like to learn suggestions on how to extract the patterns for real images. Thanks very much.

Comment: I would not address this in the Fourier domain, but if you want to do it, you should mask out the spectrum with the spectrum of the grid lines only (fourth row, fifth column) !

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @YvesDaoust. Do you mean to apply the mask from my synthetic image to real image? I might be able to do so, but the real image could be different from the synthetic grid lines a little (e.g. bolder, different gap between dashes, slightly tilted, etc.).
And I'd love to learn your solution as well. Any suggestion is welcomed :)

Comment: Masking the image with itself is a nonsense !

Comment: Sure. I do not mean to mask the image with itself. I think what you suggested is: apply (4th row, 5th col) as mask to (1st row, 3rd/4th col), right?
And you suggested that the Fourier domain might not be the best way. Could you elaborate the suggested way? Thanks.

Comment: Better try to detect the lines in the spatial domain (Hough) and erase them.